# creating html email format inside var html = string.Format

Tags: asp.net, html-email

Good Day.

I am creating an html email in ASP.NET. Now the problem  is when I want to add anything to my body except the html and body tags. When I want to add styles, the code file gives me errors, and many of them...

I want to add this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Enquiry</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div style="margin: 0 auto; text-align: center; background: #3C3B3D; padding: 10px;">
        <h4 style="color: #F3911F">Website Enquiry</h4>
    </div>
    <table style="text-align: center; margin: 0 auto;">
        <tr>
            <td>name: </td>
            <td>{0}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Inside this

```
var html = string.Format("THE HTML HERE", TextBoxName.Text)
```

Visual studio basically underlines everything (all the html above) when I add it to the string...

How do I format/style my email body in ASP?.

Thank you

Comment: What does your HTML email have to do with `TextBoxName.Text`?

Comment: Use stringbuilder to construct the body in html format and send mail. Please ensure to change the mail body format property to html in code. (I.e.,) obj.format = mailformat.html;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape all quote characters. There are two options:

```
// for single line texts use \
var x = "abcd\"efg\"hij";

// for multiple lines use @ and double quotes
var x = @"abcd
""efg""
hij";
```

When using `String.Format` you also have to escape any `{}` characters that might appear (for example, in CSS or JavaScript blocks, using double `{{}}`

```
var x = string.Format("This is the value: {0} and this is just the brackets {{asd}}", 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use StringBulider.Append()

A simple mail sending code is [here](http://dotnet--solutions.blogspot.in/2013/03/send-mail-without-page-post-back-in.html)